# Wordpress Issues Regarding IP and Domain Name - Host Gator

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am hoping somebody can help me because I am on the verge of frustration tears.

The company I work for has a site hosted on godaddy and has to remain up until I complete the rebuild on hostgator, using the Wordpress theme, Grand Restaurant http://themes.themegoods2.com/?theme=GrandRestaurant

To get around the domain name issue since I cannot change nameservers yet, I had to use the Google Chrome plugin, Virtual Hosts, which has me input the IP and domain, to force access to the site.

Everything was working fine until I needed to use the "content builder." If you look at the Grand Restaurant theme, you can click on Menu. I need to use the "Menu Grid" option in the content builder but it does not work. Whenever I try to add the menu grid, it appears that it is trying to load (showing the gif loading image) yet in never actually loads. I have spent several days and hours going back and forth with host gator and the theme developer.

The theme developer says that the content builder does not work because:
**"The WordPress URL and Site URL are set to the domain name. When you are logged in, you are being redirected to the IP, so the browser sees 2 different sites and some functionality ex. AJAX call doesn't allow you to get data from different URLs.
Your WordPress URL and Site URL settings are different from your actual site. You have to change your Domain Name URL and Site URL settings to the IP number."**

I did what he said earlier today and it completely broke the site. Spent nearly 2 hours with host gator's tech support to get it back up. All tech support will tell me in regards to the content builder not working is that I need to change the AJAX file to allow the site URL and wordpress URL to be different. I have no idea how to do that!

Any wisdom you all could provide would be greatly appreciated. I have 1700 bakery items that I need  upload by the end of July and I do not know what I am going to do if I cannot get the content builder working.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work properly you should be using a method of back up and restore. By migrating from one hosting provider to another you could simply deploy the new Wordpress on host gator as a new site and import the Wordpress backup to the host gator with the many different plugins available through Wordpress. The way your trying to complete this is impossible and usually will only work with images and back ups being managed on virtual machines, and VPS. It won't hurt anything on the original up and running site. You mentioned that host gator was able to get the site back up? You shouldn't have to rebuild this if you use a back up and restore method. Everything should fall right into place, you can also test these methods through virtual box, and VMware virtualization products which offer trial versions. Try using a migration method and see if the conflicts still persist with the content builder.

Comment: Unfortunately, the company used godaddy's awful built in instapage/ website builder. It doesn't even allow FTP access! I do not think there is anyway I can get Wordpress with instapage.

Answer (score 0):

Heres is what I would do if you cannot change the domain over but still use the domain for the dev environment.

1. [Modify your hosts](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/) file and use hostgators IP and the company domain as the entry.
2. Install wordpress to the current company domain by simply entering the domain (Should go to hostgators server since you've added that entry in your hosts file)
3. With the hosts file modification, you should be able to view the wordpress site thats hosted with hostgator using the live domain name.

This way, when you're launching, theres no need to do any modification on wordpress. Simply change the DNS over, revert your hosts file and the site will swap over seamlessly.